# Access network from watchOS 3?

Tags: ios, ios10, watchos-3

I have an RSS reader which works on watchOS 2. However, it does not work now on watchOS 3. Nothing is loaded and empty screen is shown.

I have set "App Transport Security Settings/Allow Arbitrary Loads" to `yes` in `info.plist` and watchOS 3 still have issue. Attempting to load an file in http fails to load. Nothing happened in this code.

```
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf:URL(string:url)!)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
```

I have also tried setting the info.plist in watchApp and I got this warning message:

[![Info.plist][1]][1]

What do I need to do to access network in watchOS 3?

Comment: There's a new minimum TLS protocol version policy for iOS 10. *Also keep in mind that ATS will be required as of January 1, 2017. See the [What's New in Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706) session for more details.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Setting App Transport Security Settings/Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES works in iOS beta 5 widget, but I still got issue with watchOS.